# Launching survey window when user exits site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a survey request that will be presented to a small percentage of website visitors.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to launch the survey when the user leaves the site. Initially, I was thinking of a pop-under that the user would happen upon when the closed their browser window - but I'm afraid this is probably deprecated and likely to be suppressed by the browser.  I'm wondering if someone more clever than I has an idea that might work.

I am using a lightbox style window to ask users if they'd be willing to a survey:

JQuery

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a#showSurvey").click(function(){
                $("#lightbox, #lightboxPanel").fadeIn(300);
            })
            $("a#closeSurvey").click(function(){
                $("#lightbox, #lightboxPanel").fadeOut(300);
            })
        })
    </script>
```

HTML

```
  <div id="lightboxPanel"> 
  <h1>We  want your opinion.</h1> 
  <p>Would you be willing to take a short survey when you've finished viewing our site?
  <p align="center"> 
  <a href="#">Sure</a>  // launch the new window after a user is done with site??
  <a id="closeSurvey" href="#">No thanks.</a> //This closes the lightbox
  </p> 
  </div>
  <div id="lightbox"></div>
```

I'm not sure if there is anyway good way to do this with JS.  Perhaps this is something that should be handled with the session on the server side.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into .unload() http://api.jquery.com/unload/ and prompt them to take the survey upon `$(window).unload().`

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert('Would you like to take our survey?');
});
```

Comment: Does .unload work when a user leaves a domain, or only a page?